# Meaning of phrase "Не позволишь жизнь скомкати" from song Дом Xрустальный

Tags: перевод

I would translate **Не позволишь жизнь скомкати** as "you will not allow life to get muffed up". I realize this is not a very poetic translation. It is taken from the following quatrain:

Если беден я, как пес, один, 
И в дому моем шаром кати - 
Ведь поможешь ты мне, господи! 
**Не позволишь жизнь скомкати**...

Also, I am not sure about the grammatical role of the word **скомкати**. Is it in the imperative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not an imperative. It is an infinitive, "скомкать". 
The form you found is archaic (or, in this case it would be the same, used as  a Church Slavonic word). The modern Russian infinitive ending -ть is derived from the old one -ти.

Here it used for some poetic reason, or maybe just for a better rhyme.
Hence it is (lyric enough) poetry, "muffed up" probably is not the  best translation. The direct "to crumple"  would be the best, I guess.

The imperative would be "скомкай", "скомкайте" for plural.

Comment: So, is "кати" of this same archaic Church Slavonic form?

Comment: No, now that one IS an imperative :) - of "катить".

Answer (score 5):

*-ти, -ть, -чь* are variations of the same infinitive suffix in complementary distribution: *-ть* is used when unstressed (*да́ть, бра́ть*), *-ти* when stressed (*мести́, нести́*), and *-чь* when the stem ending is a velar stop (*к* or *г*): *печь (пеку), стричь (стригу)* etc.

However, in poetic speech *-ть* and *-ти* (as well as *-чь* and now extinct *-чи*) are in free variation, dictated by rhythm, rhyme and meter:

> Но ка́к / проне́сть / мне э́/тот во́/рох
>   Призна́/ний че́/рез ва́ш / поро́г?

Here, the iamb (two-syllable foot with the stress on the last syllable) requires *пронесть* to be a two-syllable oxytone (a word with the stress on the last syllable).

> Дай к тебе́ нам, / по тебе́ нам, / мать, ступа́ти
>   В час вече́рний, / на моско́вском, / на Арба́те.

And here, the third paean (four-syllable foot with the stress on the third syllable) requires *ступати* to be a three-syllable paroxytone (a word with the stress on the penultimate syllable).

So, answering your question, *ско́мкати* is a poetic variation of the infinitive *ско́мкать*.

Answer (score 2):

> "you will not allow life to get muffed up"

I would add that it's more specifically "won't let *me* mess up my life" (don't know if that's obvious from the other explanations).

The less formal meaning of комкать is to do something carelessly, or in a sloppy way, and can also mean to abridge/shorten. So, "throw away" may be a reasonable translation, but that's taking a lot of liberties, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> I would translate Не позволишь жизнь скомкати as "you will not allow life to get muffed up".

You are right.

"Скомкати" is a [Church Slavonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Slavonic_language) form of verb "скомкать", "crumple". Church Slavonic language is used in prayers.